# To start a new activity in Android , do I need to use intents?

Tags: android

If I want to start a new activity after a user selects an item from a list , do I have to use Intents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The only way to start an activity is to use `startActivity()` (or `startActivityForResult()`), and each takes an `Intent`.

Comment: thank you, i thought fragments may have been an option , but Intents seem a little easier.

Comment: @user3395349: Fragments are an option for your UI. However, your question does not mention fragments. You asked if you needed to use `Intents` to start an activity.

Comment: If you are confused between choosing Fragment vs Activity approach, I would like to suggest to use Fragments for most UI elements. Don't go for "easier", Fragments seem a little tough to implement but will benefit greatly in your development.